# How to expose the data service using wso2ei

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am new to this area, can anyone please help me on this. Below is my requirement.

I have a data source and i want to access those data through REST service, i have created a data source and its giving response when executing as CURL command. Further what i want to do is need to expose that as REST service in WSO2EI and the endpoint have to be configured/publish in wso2 API manager.

Please guide me on the flow how to achieve this, I have tried my best but i couldn't make much progress.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a DSS server or the data source is there in the EI? If the data source is in the EI, you can simply generate a data service from it and that service will be accessible via an endpoint.

Comment: I am using DSS server , having a separate postgres database and created a DSS by referring the Exposing a Datasource as a Data Service topic from wso2EI documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create DSS REST services by creating ODATA service [[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Exposing+Data+as+an+OData+Service)]. If you are using ODATA, you do not need to manually define CURD operations. DSS server will automatically map RDBMS database with CURD operations.

Otherwise you can create custom REST service with Data services as it described in here[[2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Exposing+a+Datasource+as+a+Data+Service)]. Here you can define a REST service along with the SQL query that need to execute for particular request.

I found this blog[[3](https://medium.com/wso2-learning/how-to-expose-your-database-as-a-managed-api-with-wso2-in-10-minutes-c9ac2595738b)] that contain instruction to expose Data service with WSO2 API manager with an example. This example generate ODATA service with WSO2EI and expose as managed API with WSO2 API manager as following diagram.
[image]

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Exposing+Data+as+an+OData+Service
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Exposing+a+Datasource+as+a+Data+Service
3. https://medium.com/wso2-learning/how-to-expose-your-database-as-a-managed-api-with-wso2-in-10-minutes-c9ac2595738b